# Automate the way to get the nodes that are ready

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

newbie here . I am trying to automate the way to get the nodes that are ready using the following script:

`until kubectl get nodes | grep -m 2 "Ready"; do sleep 1 ; done`

Is there a better way to do this, specifically i am looking for a way to do this without having to specify the node number?

Answer (score 1):

To get the names of all `Ready` nodes, use

```sh
$ kubectl get nodes -o json | jq -r '.items[] | select(.status.conditions[].type=="Ready") | .metadata.name '

master-0
node-1
node-3
node-x
```

Answer (score 0):

Basing on the official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#viewing-finding-resources)

You can check your ready nodes by using this command:

```
JSONPATH='{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.name}:{range @.status.conditions[*]}{@.type}={@.status};{end}{end}' \
 && kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath="$JSONPATH" | grep "Ready=True"
```

You don't need to specify number of nodes in your command, just use it like this:

```
until kubectl get nodes | grep -i "Ready"; do sleep 1 ;  done
```